# How to keep the fgcolor of SpecialKey when :set list

Tags: vim

I have this in my vimrc:

```
hi CursorLine   guibg=#DDDDDD

hi SpecialKey   guifg=#d8a080   gui=italic

set listchars=tab:»\ ,trail:·,extends:»,precedes:«,eol:¶

set CursorLine

set list
```

When I move the cursor around, the fgcolor of the current line's SpecialKeys becomes black!

How can I keep them `#d8a080` and italic?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your _vimrc is not broken. I tested below.

```
# cat > foo.vim
hi CursorLine   guibg=#DDDDDD
hi SpecialKey   guifg=#d8a080   gui=italic
hi Constant   guifg=#d8a080   gui=italic
set listchars=tab:»\ ,trail:·,extends:»,precedes:«,eol:¶
set cursorline
set list
^D

# vim foo.vim
```

I could see the cursorline is fill with lightgray, and "#DDDDDD" (is Constant) is italic.
And, I did below to show SpecifalKey.

```
:map
v  <C-X>         "*d
...
```

I could see `<C-X>` is italic.